# Frontend accessing MongoDb

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

For a project, we're going to use the MEAN stack. Having Angularjs as the frontend framework, is there a possibility for the framework directly accessing the data from mongodb (Bypassing node and express)?

Also, is it possible to use meteorjs on the client side? If ever, what are key advantages and can it do direct access to mongodb as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frontend accesing MongoDB is possible, via its HTTP (rest) interface
http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/

To get the contents of a collection (note the trailing slash):

```
http://127.0.0.1:28017/databaseName/collectionName/
```

To add a limit:

```
http://127.0.0.1:28017/databaseName/collectionName/?limit=-10
```

To skip:

```
http://127.0.0.1:28017/databaseName/collectionName/?skip=5
```

To query for {a : 1}:

```
http://127.0.0.1:28017/databaseName/collectionName/?filter_a=1
```

Separate conditions with an &:

```
http://127.0.0.1:28017/databaseName/collectionName/?filter_a=1&limit=-10
```

Same as db.$cmd.findOne({listDatabase:1}) on the admin database in the shell:

```
http://localhost:28017/admin/$cmd/?filter_listDatabases=1&limit=1
```

To count documents in a collection:

```
http://host:port/db/$cmd/?filter_count=collection&limit=1
```

However, I personally discourage this approach. Node/Express can be a simple wrapper for auth/auth before you make any changes to DB.

Comment: i got this msg when i try to access to the list of the db in mengo from the webbrowser "REST is not enabled.  use --rest to turn on.
check that port 28017 is secured for the network too." do you have any idea to resolve this error ...